# Qt 5.0 and c++11 with OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, qt5

I'm giving c++ a try again after being away for 7 years. I've downloaded the newly released Qt 5.0 sdk for osx, but I can't get a basic c++11 feature compiled using Qt Creator. The following statement:

```
auto i = 3;
```

results in a compilation error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'i' with no type
```

I've google around for similar problems and found suggestions to put

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
  or
CONFIG += c++11
```

in the .pro file. Unfortunately without success .The build fails on unrecognized command line options.

I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Frans

Comment: What compiler (and version) do you have installed?

Comment: I've the latest version of xcode and the command line tools that come with it: version 4.5.2 (4G2008a). In Xcode itself, it's no problem to work with c++11 features. Also, building boost 1.52 did just work.

Comment: GCC 4.5 doesn't have a `c++11` standard mode, it has `c++0x` instead.

Comment: Using c++0x in the .pro file in stead of c++11 shows the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? Same thing is happening to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066068/how-to-program-c11-using-qt5

Comment: @ccSadegh: That's a different compiler on a different platform, and is the wrong solution for Xcode on the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like Qt Creator for Mac bug.
I fixed it using

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
LIBS += -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

in .pro file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you.

On my current system (Max OS X Yosemite - Qt 5.4 - QtCreator 3.0 - XCode 6.1.1) this works like a charm:

In .pro file:

```
macx {
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
    QMAKE_CFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
    QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9
}

macx {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
    QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
}
CONFIG += c++11
```

Make sure you have the latest Mac OS X SDK installed too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [gcc feature list](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), `auto` is supported since `gcc 4.4`through:

```
g++ -std=c++0x
```

you could also try the `gcc-specific` form:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x
```

Maybe, in your case, an additional problem occurs (g++ parameters not correctly promoted to the compiler).

Comment: Thanks. No luck unfortunately. I suspect that the problem is related to the way the Qt 5.0 sdk for Mac is build (clang vs. g++). But I don't know enough about the XCode tools and/or Qt to proceed. I didn't find the Qt documentation helpful in this respect.